# How can I return distinct objects from an array?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

**I use this approach(not good)**

```
function unique(objArray){
```

**uArray is temporary array variable to hold objects as strings**

```
 var uArray=[];
```

**this function return arr**

```
  var arr=[];
```

**Each object convert to string**

```
 for(var i=0;i<objArray.length;i++){
 if(typeof objArray[i] === "object")
 uArray[i]=JSON.stringify(objArray[i]);
 }
```

**push strings to newArray arr**

```
 for( i=0;i<uArray.length;i++){
 if( arr.indexOf(uArray[i]) === -1)
 {
  arr.push(uArray[i]);
 }

 }
```

**Parse strings to objects**

```
 for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
  arr[i]=JSON.parse(arr[i]);
 }
 return arr;
 }
```

**sample input array **

```
var users = [
 { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
 { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true },
 { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
 { 'user': 'salman',    'age': 50, 'active': false },
 { 'user': 'usman',    'age': 44, 'active': false },
 { 'user': 'abrar',    'age': 22, 'active': false },
 {'K1':21, 'k2':22},
 { firstName:'XYZ',lastName'ABC'},`
 { firstName:'XYZ',lastName:'ABC'},
 { firstName:'XYZ1',lastName:'ABC1'}
 ];

      unique(users);
```

Comment: What isn't clear from your question is what you expect the output array to look like. At first glance all of those objects in the input array are unique.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have 2 `{ firstName:'XYZ',lastName'ABC'}` objects.

Comment: yes there can be more same objects

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function unique(objArray){

  return objArray.filter(function(inst, i){
      for(var j=i+1; j<objArray.length; j++){
          if(JSON.stringify(objArray[j])==JSON.stringify(inst)) return false;
      }
      return true;
  });

}
```

[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vns176om/)

Answer (score 1):

`map` the objects to strings like you were doing, `filter` the duplicates out, then re`map` the objects back.

```
function unique(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(el) {
    return JSON.stringify(el);
  }).filter(function(e, i, a) {
    return a.indexOf(e) === i;
  }).map(function(el) {
    return JSON.parse(el);
  });
}

unique(users);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/v4bktgke/1/)

Answer (score -3):

I see that you want to remove duplicates from your array. You can do it with `unique` function of *underscore*.

I recommend you to do it easily by using *underscore* Utility for javascript (link below).

Using underscore:

```
_.uniq(inputArray) // Return unique keys
```

> Produce a duplicate-free version of the array. If the array has
>   already been sorted

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-60

The source code for this function:

```
  _.uniq = function(array, isSorted, iteratee, context) {
    if (!_.isBoolean(isSorted)) {
      context = iteratee;
      iteratee = isSorted;
      isSorted = false;
    }
    if (iteratee != null) iteratee = cb(iteratee, context);
    var result = [];
    var seen = [];
    for (var i = 0, length = getLength(array); i < length; i++) {
      var value = array[i],
          computed = iteratee ? iteratee(value, i, array) : value;
      if (isSorted) {
        if (!i || seen !== computed) result.push(value);
        seen = computed;
      } else if (iteratee) {
        if (!_.contains(seen, computed)) {
          seen.push(computed);
          result.push(value);
        }
      } else if (!_.contains(result, value)) {
        result.push(value);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
```

### Example:

```html
<script src="//underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
  b={t:'B is Object'}
var a=[1,2,3,3,'4',b,'4',b]

document.write('Before Unique:<br>')
document.write(a)
document.write('<br>')
document.write('After Unique:<br>')
document.write  (_.unique(a))
  </script>
```

Comment: code does not work for array of anonymous objetcs like

Comment: var users = [
 { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
 { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true },
 { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
 { 'user': 'salman',    'age': 50, 'active': false },
 { 'user': 'usman',    'age': 44, 'active': false },
 { 'user': 'abrar',    'age': 22, 'active': false },
 {'K1':21, 'k2':22},
 { firstName:'XYZ',lastName'ABC'},`
 { firstName:'XYZ',lastName:'ABC'},
 { firstName:'XYZ1',lastName:'ABC1'}
 ];